# How to prevent the use of a phone as a second-factor security confirmation

Tags: security, lost-phone

Mobile phones are frequently used to read email and access secure online accounts.  So the average phone contains both the account signon usernames and the associated passwords.  Email has been used for resetting a password, and is also accessible using the phone.  Recently many host sites have started using text messages a second factor security mechanism.

The popular use of mobile phones as a second-factor security mechanism has inadvertently caused a huge security problem.  The odds are much higher that your phone will be lost or stolen than you becoming a victim of an online attack or suffering the compromise of your online account password.  Since a typical phone grants access to everything, including the ability to reset passwords and get past 2-factor security based on your device, the phone has become a valuable target for theft much more than ever before.

So now if your phone is lost or stolen, the attacker will be able to access everything the phone has been enabled to access.  And you will not be able to access ANYTHING without your phone.  You may not even be able to reset your password or lock your accounts.

Is there any way to stop the use of a text message as a second-factor account confirmation?  I would prefer the use of personal questions to confirm my identity.  The only alternative I know of is to not use your phone at all for email or accessing high-value online accounts.  And I highly recommend you enable tracking to allow you to find a lost or stolen phone quickly.

Comment: I assume by "text message" you are referring to SMS as second factor. There is a simple way to prevent access to a phone if it is stolen: set an access PIN that has at least 6 digits (for comfort you can use the fingerprint unlock). As modern Android devices are encrypted by default the only way to bypass this PIN is to guess it (if the PIN was chosen too simple) or to rob the phone while it is unlocked.

Comment: I have both pin and biometric in use, and of course, I very highly recommend doing so. But it is easy to watch someone entering their pin and targeting their phone afterward. The use of the phone as a second-factor is not only an undesired nuisance and security problem - but it also prevent accessing (or locking) any accounts without phone service.

Comment: Hi, since this question is asked on Android Enthusiasts, a Q&A for Android end-users (not necessarily security experts, though we also have a sister site [security.se] for this), the answers will focus on what *end-users* can do, not what service providers can do. Though, I actually doubt end-users can do anything else as long as they're dependent to what the service only provides, other than preparing for risk mitigation (what can be done if stolen).

Comment: Most services support to use different type of seconds factor that work offline (e.g. 2FA-app based, or dedicated hardware based token). You can also use a cheap Android phone or tablet as dedicated 2FA-hardware you always leave at home.

Comment: Yes Information Security might be a better forum. And this is a security problem bigger than Android for sure.  From an Android standpoint, setting up your device so that it can be located (when powered up) is critical to minimizing risk.  The user must be able to do so very quickly.  With Apple devices all you need is an online browser to locate your device.  Its a bit more complicated with Android.

Comment: To Robert.  Until recently the use of HW tokens and FIDO devices was a great alternative.  But sites such as Blink and Nextdoor havent become this sophisticated yet.  I have been using a tablet for accessing email and high-value sites.  But they are now frequently re-authenticating which requires my phone and is the equivalent of resetting my password every time I signon which has become painful.  Like having to solve a captcha which was the last security trend.  Google sends and email if anyone unfamiliar accesses my account.  This is an excellent, and painless, security measure.